# Render different charts depending on dropdown value in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, google-visualization

I have a mat-select with some options, and am rendering a google line chart based on the data of `value` mapped to the particular options.

When I change the selection, I can see the `value` changing with the `selectionChange($event)` function, and the data that I want is also correct, however, the chart div is not getting updated / re-rendered.

How do I make it update on option change.

Here's some of my code:

```
<mat-form-field class="cDropdown">
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="ids[a.name]"  panelClass="selectplantdropdown" (selectionChange)="onChangeEvent($event)">
        <mat-option [value]=a.id>{{ a.name }}</mat-option>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let b of temp">
        <mat-option [value]=b.id (click)="switchCustomer()">
          {{ b.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </ng-container>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

This is the div for the line-chart

```
<div style="font-weight: bolder; padding: 10% 40%">{{ chartData[ids[a.name]][0].data[1] }} {{ ids[a.name] }} CHART GOES HERE
</div> /*I can see the values changing here as well*/
<div>
     <app-linechart [data]="chartData[ids[a.name]][0].data" [config]="config" [elementId]="ids[a.name]"></app-linechart>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
This is the onChangeEvent($event) function from the .ts file

```
onChangeEvent(event) {
    console.log(event.value);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.chartData[event.value][0].data));
}
```

Comment: Share your ts code

Comment: please add code from .ts file

Comment: please share `onChangeEvent` function body

Comment: I've shared the code from the.ts file. Please have a look.